# IE10 won't fire the animation (Horizontally moving pic)

Tags: css, animation, internet-explorer-10

I've got a bit of a problem with a CSS3-animation that is not firing in IE10.

I basically have a static image that is mostly transparent but with a few details, behind it there is a background image that is supposed to move horizontally. It works well in Chrome, but not in IE10 (win7), and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

All kinds of tips and tricks would be much appreciated.

```html
<div id="skyover">
    <img src="hh_sky_transp2.png" alt="logo" width="1000" height="202" />
</div>
<div id="sky">
    <img src="hh_sky.jpg" alt="logo" width="2016" height="202" />
</div>
```

```css
#skyover {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}

#sky { 
    width: 1000px;
    height: 202px;
    position: relative;
    animation: skymove 10s infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation: skymove 10s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes skymove {
    from { left: 0px; }
    to { right: 1000px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes skymove {
    from { left: 0px; }
    to { right: 1000px; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a jsFiddle or the original code, so that we can see the code in acton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is animating from a left-origin to a right-origin:

```
@keyframes skymove {
    from { left: 0px }
    to { right: 1000px }
}
```

If you change the `to` point-of-origin to `left`, the issue is resolved:

```
@keyframes skymove {
    from { left:0px }
    to { left: 1000px }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HGe5D/2/show/

Comment: Thanks! Didn't cross my mind, but I think I messed it up myself somewhere in the process of trying to solve some other problem.

Comment: If you're going to use vendor prefixes don't forget `-o-`, and `-moz-` too.